# Why Uncaught type of error in the JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello everyone I have problem i building my first sit But it gives this error it's problem about html Or not ?
I checked everything can anyone help me?[this error[this is my js cods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aluNO.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPlPn.jpg)

I try html cods and js cods but i But I have no experience and I am self-taught

Comment: Please post your code as text, as links to images can break, and images are not easily searchable, nor copy/pasteable.

Comment: Hi, Look like you're importing the personal.js file twice, could you edit your question to put the HTML code with the `<script ...>` balise (adding the javascript code and errors as text rather than image would be nice too) :)

Comment: We would also want *all* of the relevant code, including the HTML in question. According to the error message, it seems as if `navMenuBtn` or `navCloseBtn` don't exist. But we can't tell what's going on because we can't see the html.

Comment: Looking at the screen shots, the `python` tag doesn't seem relevant.